# Using ZK Tree component, how do I remove Treeitems from a Treechildren node

Tags: tree, zk

Does anyone know how to remove Treeitems from a Treechildren node in ZK? I have tried using an iterator and removeChild but a ConcurrentModificationException!

```
List<Treeitem> myTreeItems = treechildren.getChildren();

Iterator<Treeitem> iterator = myTreeItems.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
   myItem = (Treeitem)iterator.next();
   parent.removeChild(myItem);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the correct way to remove the items, you need to do something like this.

```
while (parent.getItemCount() > 0) {
   parent.removeChild(parent.getFirstChild());
}
```

This will provide the functionality that you require!

More details on using the Tree component are available [here.](http://docs.zkoss.org/wiki/Grids,_Trees_and_Listbox#Tree_Controls)

Answer (score 0):

As what I saw in your case you want to remove all components which are all attached on a `treechildren`. 
I think the fastest way is:

```
treechildren.getChildren().clear();
```

just operate the result like a `java.util.List`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Vbox hbC;

hbC.appendChild(hijo1);

hbC.appendChild(hijo2);

for(int i = 0; 
  i< hbC.getChildren().size(); i++){

            hbC.removeChild(hbC.getChildren().get(i));
        } 

optional

try{

if(hbC.getChildren().size()>0){

for (Component c : hbC.getChildren()) {

           hbC.removeChild(c);
}

}

 1. List item

}catch()
```